# WebRTC iOS local video track not render on RTCEAGLVideoView

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I want render local camera capturer's video track on RTCEAGLView instead of RTCCameraPreviewView before connect to room. I created a local video track as below in viewDidLoad:

```
    let dF = RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory.init()
    let eF = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory.init()
    eF.preferredCodec = ARDSettingsModel.init().currentVideoCodecSettingFromStore()
    RTCPeerConnectionFactory.init()
    let factory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory.init(encoderFactory: eF, decoderFactory: dF)
    let videoSource = factory.videoSource()
    capturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.init(delegate: videoSource)
    capturerController = ARDCaptureController.init(capturer: capturer, settings: ARDSettingsModel.init())
    capturerController?.startCapture()
    let rtcTrack = factory.videoTrack(with: videoSource, trackId: "ARDAMSv0")
    let localView = RTCEAGLVideoView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(localView)
    rtcTrack.add(localView)
```

The RTCEAGLVideoView did added as subview, but the track did not render on the view, anyone know why?

I have success get preview view by RTCCameraPreviewView if using:

```
    let localView2 = RTCCameraPreviewView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
    localView2.captureSession = capturer?.captureSession
    self.view.addSubview(localView2)
```

Comment: Which version of webrtc are you using?

Comment: I am using GoogleWebRTC 1.1.24275 and installed from cocoapod.

Comment: I'm using version [1.1.25](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC) and capturing the local video with RTCEAGLView and **startCaptureWithDevice** function